# Current-Mode Logic Explanation

Tags: emc, hdmi, high-speed

I was reading about the HDMI standard and therefore the [CML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current-mode_logic) logic, and some alegations are not clear for me about the advantages of the CML.

One of its advantages is the low output voltage swing, so signals varies just some millivolts (about between Vcc and Vcc-0,4V), and thus creating less EMI...but with signals being so small aren't they MORE vulnerable to EMI?

As far as I can see only having a 0,4V swing between 0 and 1 makes any possible form of interference a major issue, isn't it?

I couldn't find many good explanations about the standard online, so any good explanations about it's features and workings are most welcome.

Comment: It is not that vulnerable because the load impedance is fairly low. And interference couples to both conductors with same amplitude, so it is zeroed out at the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

The main link from your link explains it much more and better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emitter-coupled_logic

The EMI reduction is due to less changes in the supply rail movement which is galvanically connected to the signals. This tends to have a much greater impact to the signal than radio waves coupling into the signal channel.

It being differential in nature also lends itself to cancellation of radio waves coupling into the signal path as anything that couples into one line will also couple into the other at about the same amount cancelling most common-mode noise.

Some of the advantages this has over other common amplifying schemes are due to the low-output impedance and the removal of the miller effect unlike standard digital logic drive devices. Digital logic basically has everything setup like common-source amplifiers so the output impedance is high, the voltage gain is high, and consequently the miller-effect reduces high frequency performance.

Comment: You might want to explain how CML is different from ECL, and why the benefits of ECL still apply to CML.

Comment: @ThePhoton That's just about reaching the extent that I know. CML sounds like a superset containing ECL and SCL. Obviously you know more. Care to enlighten us? :)

Comment: I just thought ECL was a pretty old technology, I never bothered much about reading about it...time to be more "humble" with the old school....

Comment: @mFeinstein For sure. The guys who started working on transistors and triodes 50-70 years ago were no dumb bunnies. They continue to blow me away the more I learn more about electronics (and its past).

Comment: @horta, yep, gotta admire what they did with so less...